# Can one specify serde's rename_all rule at runtime?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a data model that I would like to be deserialized from `"camelCase"` to the rust standard `"snake_case"` when reading from a source, **X**. But I'd like to leave it in `"snake_case"` when reading or writing to another source, **Y**.

For example, the following code,

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Data {
  foo_bar: String,
  hello_word: String,
}
```

can only be encoded and decoded in camel case.  Even if I manually defined my `Serialize` and `Deserialize` implementations, I can't define multiple for the same struct.  I could define a second struct that's a copy/paste of the other and then derive but that method would get tedious with multiple large structs.  What I would really like to do is specify that `rename_all` attribute at run-time.  But I'm not seeing any way to do that in serde's API.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a custom `Serializer` that e.g. takes an instance of `T: Serialize` and a `Serializer`, then delegates to the `Serializer` but changes the case of all keys? Then you could create a wrapper/newtype for any `T: Serialize` that implements `Serialize` using your custom serializer. However this would be very difficult and probably inefficient due to runtime converting...

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way *sigh* is to just write out one struct `Data_` per `#[serde(rename_all = ...)]`, then write one additional struct `Data` that will be the in-memory representation (which won't be serializable, to remove ambiguity), then implement `From` in both directions for the `Data_`s and `Data` so that they're interconvertible.

Thankfully, we can use a macro so that we only have to specify the fields once. (It is incredibly disgusting nonetheless.)

This playground available [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a18c6506e98d62d7a67c849f69a4bcb).

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.130
use serde_json; // 1.0.69

macro_rules! interconvertible {
    ($T:ident <-> $U:ident, $($field_name:ident),*) => {
        impl From<$T> for $U {
            fn from(t: $T) -> Self {
                let $T { $($field_name),* } = t;
                Self { $($field_name),* }
            }
        }

        impl From<$U> for $T {
            fn from(u: $U) -> Self {
                let $U { $($field_name),* } = u;
                Self { $($field_name),* }
            }
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! create_data_structs {
    ($($field_name:ident: $field_type:ty),* $(,)?) => {
        #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
        #[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
        struct DataX {
            $($field_name: $field_type),*
        }

        #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
        #[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
        struct DataY {
            $($field_name: $field_type),*
        }

        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct Data {
            $($field_name: $field_type),*
        }

        interconvertible!(DataX <-> Data, $($field_name),*);
        interconvertible!(DataY <-> Data, $($field_name),*);
    }
}

create_data_structs!(foo_bar: String, hello_world: String);

fn main() -> serde_json::Result<()> {
    let x1: DataX = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"fooBar": "a", "helloWorld": "b"}"#)?;
    let y1: DataY = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"foo_bar": "a", "hello_world": "b"}"#)?;
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", x1, y1);

    let x2: Data = x1.into();
    let y2: Data = y1.into();
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", x2, y2);

    let x_string = serde_json::to_string(&DataX::from(x2))?;
    let y_string = serde_json::to_string(&DataY::from(y2))?;
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", x_string, y_string);

    Ok(())
}
```

The output is:

```
DataX { foo_bar: "a", hello_world: "b" }, DataY { foo_bar: "a", hello_world: "b" }
[Data { foo_bar: "a", hello_world: "b" }, Data { foo_bar: "a", hello_world: "b" }]
"{\"fooBar\":\"a\",\"helloWorld\":\"b\"}", "{\"foo_bar\":\"a\",\"hello_world\":\"b\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm only every decoding from source **X** I can utilize the `#[serde(alias = ???)]` macro.  So my above use case would be

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Data {
  #[serde(alias="fooBar")]
  foo_bar: String,
  #[serde(alias="helloWorld")]
  hello_word: String,
}
```

It's still a little tedious but better than an intermediate struct.  It won't work though if I want to decode or encode to different cases.

(*I'm not going to mark this as an answer because it's a work-around for my specific use case.  If anyone has a more generic solution feel free to answer.*)